# String matching in perl (if statement in for loop)

Tags: perl

I have following code

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin -w
#use strict; use warnings;
init_words();
print "What is your name Mr. \n";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp ($name);
if ($name =~ /^randal\b/i){
    print "Hello, Randal, How are you doing \n";
} else {
   print "Hello, $name!\n";
   print "Tell the secret word\n";
   $guess = <STDIN>;
   chomp ($guess);
   while (!good_word ($name,$guess)) {
       print "Wrong, please try again\n";
       $guess = <STDIN>;
       chomp ($guess);
   }
}

sub init_words {
    open (WORDSLIST, "wordslist.txt") || die "can't open wordslist: $!";
$k = 1;
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
while (defined ($name = <WORDSLIST>)) {
    if ($k % 2 == 0) { 
        chomp ($name);
        $words1[$a] = $name;
        ++$k;
        ++$a; 
    } else {
        chomp ($name);
        $words2[$b] = $name;
        ++$k;
        ++$b;
    }
}

close (WORDSLIST) || die "couldn't close wordlist: $!";
}

sub good_word {
    my ($somename, $someguess) = @_;
    $somename =~ s/\W.*//;
    $somename =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    if ($somename eq "randal") { 
         return 1;
    } else {
        #$n = 0;
        #words1 has secret words.
        #words2 has names.
        $t = scalar @words1;
        $u = scalar @words2;
        print "the words1 array is @words1 \n";
        print "the words2 array is @words2 \n";
        for ($d = 0; $d < $u; $d++) {
            #print "currently name in array is @words2[$d]\n";
            print "The value of somename is $somename \n";
            $delta = $words2[$d];
            print "The value of delta is $delta";
            #use strict; use warnings;
            if ($delta eq '$somename') {
                 print "test";
                 return 1;
            } 
       }
       #print "The final value of d is $d";
       #print " The final value of array is @words1[$d]";
       #if ("groucho" eq $someguess) {
       #return 1;}
       #else{
       #while ($n < $t){
       #if (@words1[$n] eq $someguess) {
       #return 1;}
       #else { ++$n};
    }
```

The main goal of the code is to have wordslist defined. The code should split the wordslist into two sublists i.e. `@words1` and `@words2`. User is asked for a name and then secret guess. The code should check for the name in the @words2 and if match is found program exit (with printing test).
For some reason, it is not working as expected. I tried doing some basic debugging and everything looks ok but in the function good_word, the if statement under for loop is never returned true although i can see in my debugging that both `$somename` and $delta are same.
Any suggestions??

Comment: Always remember to `use strict` and when it gives you an error, fix the error instead of commenting out the `use strict`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if ($delta eq '$somename'){
```

to

```
if ($delta eq $somename){
```

---

Perl strings with double quotes (`"`) will interpolate variables like `$somename` but strings with single quotes (`'`) will not do that.

Reference to documentation about that: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for response. I changed it but still not working. For easy understanding, i have another script (almost identical) i.e.                                                         $somename = <STDIN>;
@words2 = qw (john catherine alex);
$u = @words2;
for ($d = 0; $d < $u; $d++)
 {
  #print "currently name in array is @words2[$d]\n";
  #print "The value of somename is $somename \n";

  $delta = $words2[$d];
  print "The value of delta is $delta \n";
  if ($delta eq $somename){print "test";return 1;} }

Comment: In above script, if i input either of three words i.e. john, catherine or alex, it wont print test on the screen. Looks like if statement is failing for some reason.... even though if i use chomp ($somename).